# R keep only rows with a unique value in a certain column

Tags: r

I don't think this exact question has been asked since I'm not exactly trying to deduplicate. I have a data frame with several columns. One column is NAME. I want to extract only rows whose value for NAME is unique. For instance if I have:

```
NAME    V2     V3
John    9      A
John    8      B
Alex    9      A
Bret    9      A
```

Then I'd like to get:

```
NAME    V2     V3
Alex    9      A
Bret    9      A
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could accomplish this. One is:

```
df<-data.frame(NAME=c("John", "John","Alex", "Brett"), V2=c(9,8,9,9), V3=c("A","B","A","A"))


df[!df$NAME %in% names(which(table(df$NAME)>1)),]
```